# Shortcut to jump to first search result from omnibox

Tags: google-search

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to jump to first result in Google search after landing there from omnibox? Right now I need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> 18 times, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: `Tab`+`Enter` used to work, and by all indications still should, but it's not working for me. Some suggestions are to reset Google cookies and to make sure "Google Instant" is on in the settings, but that hasn't been working for me.

Comment: @AlE. same here.

Answer (score 2):

After searching, press <kbd>tab</kbd> once, and the focus will be on a "Skip to main content" link. Using that (via <kbd>enter</kbd>) will take you past the menus to where the results start.

[image: skip link under the Google logo]